# can't get the urls of articles using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request, web-crawler

I'm using BeautifulSoup to get the urls of articles from this page:
https://www.usnews.com/search?q=China+COVID-19&gsc.tab=0&gsc.q=China+COVID-19&gsc.page=1#gsc.tab=0&gsc.q=China%20COVID-19&gsc.page=1

I expect all the links of the articles should be stored in pagelinks, like this:

```
['https://www.usnews.com/news/health-news/articles/2020-04-08/chinas-controls-may-have-headed-off-700-000-covid-19-cases-study']
['https://www.usnews.com/news/health-news/articles/2020-03-18/trump-dubs-covid-19-chinese-virus-despite-hate-crime-risks']
.......
```

But the output gives me a `[]`.
I used this code:

```
            #parse the content
            soup_page = bs(response.text, 'lxml') 
            #select all the articles for a single page
            #containers = soup_page.findAll("li", {'class': 'usn-site-search-item'})
            containers = soup_page.findAll("div", {'class': 'usn-site-search-item-container'})
            #scrape the links of the articles
            for i in containers:
                url = i.find('a')
                pagelinks.append(url.get('href'))
            print(pagelinks)
```

As you see, I tried two containers, but neither gives me the expected results.

I would greatly appreciate if someone could help me out!

Answer (score 1):

That webpage loads with JavaScript. You need to go around that and one way is with Selenium.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.usnews.com/search?q=China+COVID-19&gsc.tab=0&gsc.q=China+COVID-19&gsc.page=1#gsc.tab=0&gsc.q=China%20COVID-19&gsc.page=1"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'lxml')

#the rest of your code here

driver.quit()
```

If you don't have the [Selenium package](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/) installed, this is the command to run in a terminal:

```
pip install selenium
```

Answer (score 1):

The response you get when you called the above-mentioned URL doesn't contain the links you are looking for. You might need to use headless browsers like selenium OR puppeteer since the page needs javascript to load

But you can use this URL to get the desired result [programmable search engine](https://cse.google.com/cse/element/v1?rsz=filtered_cse&num=10&hl=en&source=gcsc&gss=.com&cselibv=57975621473fd078&cx=009692862532464842631:ckoj05188pi&q=China%20COVID-19&safe=off&cse_tok=AJvRUv3i250WVSYejM2ODNDaIHE-:1590680381832&sort=&exp=csqr,cc,4355059&oq=China%20COVID-19&gs_l=partner-generic.12...0.0.0.212743.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0.csems%2Cnrl%3D13...0.0....34.partner-generic..0.0.0.&callback=google.search.cse.api2768)

Here is a small python code:

```
import requests
import json

headers = {
    "user-agent": <User Agent Goes Here>
}

res = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
json_res = res.text.split("api2768")[1][1:-2]

urls = []
for url in json.loads(json_res)['results']:
    urls.append(url['url'])
```

P.S: Please take care of the cookies